# I am unable to install angular app after installing the CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, failed-installation

Here is part of the log where the error is really logged .. but the error changes from installation attempt to the other

```
2516 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.9.1
2517 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"7.0.0-rc.0","@babe'
2517 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2517 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
```

Comment: do u have npm installed on your pc ?? what is the command you tried ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following:

npm cache clean --force
and
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: i tried your suggestion and it didn't work, but i think it is because my internet connection, i will try it with a faster connection.